# optimize bootstrap scss import

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4, angular-universal

i have an Angular4 CLI project with Universal SSR. in my own scss file i import bootstrap:

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

bootstrap itself imports a lot of other scss files, e.g.:

```
@import "transitions";
@import "dropdown";
@import "button-group";
@import "input-group";
@import "custom-forms";
@import "nav";
@import "navbar";
@import "card";
etc.
```

When I compile the angular app, it seems that a lot of unnecessary bootstrap style classes have been integrated into the bundles.

Is there a way to optimize that? Either during the import or the build process?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove things you don't need!

Instead of just importing Bootstrap as a whole, you can import all parts separately.

You can find all the parts [here](https://gist.github.com/Klooven/39e0143d63b5f4efca34c994e94770fa#file-custom-scss).

Then you can just remove the things you don't need (just make sure you leave everything in the required part of the file).

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback and thanks for your help. I also found out that I import media-breakpoint in different components SCSS files, such as `@include media-breakpoint-down (md)`

This must be outsourced in an central-SCSS file, otherwise for each component the complete bootstrap will be imported